# Detecting existence of a class member

Tags: c++, c++14, meta-programming

I wanted to detect if I have a member in a simple POD struct and after some searching and merging some methods I found on the web I've come up with this solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class...Fs>
struct funcs_t{};

template<class F0, class...Fs>
struct funcs_t<F0, Fs...>: F0, funcs_t<Fs...> {
    funcs_t(F0 f0, Fs... fs):
    F0(std::move(f0)), funcs_t<Fs...>(std::move(fs)...)
    {}
    using F0::operator();
    using funcs_t<Fs...>::operator();
};

template<class F>
struct funcs_t<F>:F {
    funcs_t(F f) : F(std::move(f)) {};
    using F::operator();
};

template<class...Fs>
funcs_t<std::decay_t<Fs>...> funcs(Fs&&...fs) {
    return {std::forward<Fs>(fs)...};
}

#define HAS_MEMBER(cls, memb)\
    [](){\
        auto with_memb = [](auto &&A, int x)\
                -> decltype(typename std::remove_reference<decltype(A)>::type().memb, std::true_type())\
        {\
            return std::true_type();\
        };\
        auto with_no_memb = [](auto &&A, float x) -> std::false_type {\
            return std::false_type();\
        };\
        auto has_memb = funcs(with_memb, with_no_memb);\
        return has_memb(cls(), 1);\
    }()

struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << HAS_MEMBER(A, b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have different pod structs with many common fields with the same meaning and I wanted to print them on screen. I will see if I can use it for other things but for now that's what I needed it for.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. If you want a fixed-version of your code to be available, post it as answer linking to Deduplicator's for credit (or post it as a new question, but it's hardly a major change).

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your detector fails in the face of overloading and templating. Also, it will only detect (static) member-variables and (static) member-functions. While you can extend it to types (and type-aliases), accepting templates and overloading would need better language-provided reflection-facilities.

   Anyway, pure existence is generally uninteresting, supported operations count.
2. `funcs()` and `funcs_t` are nearly a generally useful abstraction.

   Just use perfect forwarding instead of by-value and `std::move()`. Allowing for all callables, including `final` classes, function-pointers, member-function-pointers, and the same wrapped in a `std::reference_wrapper` would admittedly add significant amounts of code.

   A good name would be `overloaded`.
3. `HAS_MEMBER` needlessly depends on default-constructing the passed class. Fix that by using `decltype`, `std::declval()` and unevaluated contexts.
4. If you don't use an argument, don't name it. Specifically for `main()`, just don't ask for it.
5. Don't use `std::endl`. In the rare cases you actually need to flush manually, be explicit and use `std::flush`. Nearly always you are just crippling performance.
6. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`. Make of that what you will.